# Remove columns starting with numbers

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a dataframe with multiple columns starting with a number. For instance,

```
00am    00pm    02am    03am    10am    10k 11th    12th    13th ... ABC     JOIN
example example example ...       ...        ...       ...     ...  example  example
```

I would like to remove all the columns that start with a number to have

```
    ... ABC JOIN
...  example  example
```

I used `str` and `isdigit`

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.isdigit()]
```

but the result stills shows columns starting with numbers. Similarly I should exclude columns that contains numbers (I would say that in this case I should use `str.contain()`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regular expression to check the column names

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5]],columns=['0a','0b','0c','0d','e'])

    0a  0b  0c  0d  e
0   1   2   3   4   5


df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.match('^\d')]]

    e
0   5
```

Comment: Nice solution, I didn't know about this method. @Ch3steR I thought so too initially but check the docs for `str.match`, it's correct

Comment: @TobyPetty Yes true. I checked the docs. No need to add `^` tho. Nice solution

Comment: just wanted to thank you both for the help :)

Comment: Well, I noticed @Val mentioned columns "starting with numbers" so wasn't sure if it was necessary. Val, you can keep the `^` if you only want to remove columns whose names begin with numbers. Remove `^` if you want to remove columns with numbers anywhere in the name.

Comment: not the best with regex, but inspired from your method `df.filter(regex='^[^\d]')`  is also an option.. already upvoted :)

Comment: wow, not used filters myself. this is nice!

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
df[[c for c in df.columns if not re.findall("\d", c[0])]]
```

Answer (score 1):

'Loc' and 'isdigit' functions can be also used, but not in the way you wanted. You could do it differently:

```
df.loc[:, [x[0].isdigit() is False for x in df.columns]]
```

In this case we choose all rows plus columns which start from a digit.